# Django : Joining two tables and using extra field from second table for order_by

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have two models A, B

Mysql query is

```
SELECT a.ID FROM a INNER JOIN b ON ( a.ID = b.id ) WHERE ( b.key = 'vcount' ) AND (a.type = 'abc') AND (a.status = 'done') ORDER BY b.value+0 DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

//Here b.value is longtext field, so added 0 to convert to Integer, then sorted.

I need Django query for the same.

I have tried this

```
A.objects.filter(b__key ="vcount",type = "abc",status = "done").order_by('-b__value')[:5]
```

but above Django query is giving wrong result, since it is sorting by Ascii value

So need to convert 'value' field to Integer then need to sort it.

I also tried below one but giving errors

```
xyz = A.objects.filter(b__key ="vcount",type = "abc",status = "done").extra(select={'value_int': "CAST(b__value AS UNSIGNED)"}).order_by('-value_int')[:5]
```

Suggestions or Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is `b_value` in your django model? DecimalField?

Comment: Using `extra()` is the correct approach, I think. What is the error?

Comment: b is model name and value is field name. so b__value is written in order_by.

Comment: @C14L , i am not able to print/use xyz , if I try to print xyz , it is giving error like                                                                                  django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'b__value' in 'field list'")

Comment: Ok then... what is `value` in your model? A decimal field?

Comment: `b__value` is Django notation for your field name. extra() takes SQL iirc.

Comment: I'm well aware of django.... where `value` is a field of `b` but *what* type of field is it

Answer (score 0):

The `.extra()` method's `select` takes SQL, so the column name should be written as SQL `b.value`.

```
xyz = A.objects.filter(b__key ="vcount",type = "abc",status = "done")
       .extra(select={'value_int': "CAST(b.value AS UNSIGNED)"})
       .order_by('-value_int')[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm pretty sure this is the issue I'm going to write it anyway...

I'm guessing that `value` is a `DecimalField` which is stored internally as a string for indexing, which is why you are seeing strange ordering.

The solution is to change the type of value from `DecimalField` to `FloatField`